# How to read a file inside a folder which itself is inside a zip file

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip file which consists of a single folder having the same name as the zip file( ie if the name of the zip folder is 1.zip then the name of the folder inside the zip file will be 1.)
Now this folder contains a text file say atextfile.txt, I want to print the contents of this file.
I wrote the code if the atextfile.txt is just inside the zip file.

```
    for zip_name in glob.glob('[0-9].zip'):
    # the zip file name one numeric digit only.
        z=zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name)
        with z.open('atextfile.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                for word in line:
                    print word
```

I don't know what to do now. Please help.

Comment: Did you try adding a path to the filename, e.g. `z.open('1/atextfile.txt')`?

Comment: I dont know the name of the folder ( which you referred to as one) I just have it stored inside a variable that too with a name like 1.zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the path name to the filename that you are extracting with `ZipFile.open()`. Here's how to do it automatically using the naming scheme that you describe in your question:

```
for zip_name in glob.glob('[0-9].zip'):
# the zip file name one numeric digit only.
    z=zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name)
    subdir = zip_name[:-4]    # the glob pattern ensures that the file name ends with ".zip", so strip off the extension
    with z.open('{}/atextfile.txt'.format(subdir)) as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line:
                print word
```

Comment: Thanks...It is working as it was supposed to be..But can you please tell me what i should do if the zip file contains four or five digit no(ie i dont know how many digit it contains in it name).Should i change subdir = zip_name[0-4] in case of five digit no.

Comment: If you could please tell me how to do this if the no. of digits is variable in the file name.

Comment: @DeveshYadav: it's very easy and you have nearly answered it yourself: use `subdir = zip_name[:-4]` to strip off the `.zip` extension.